# Dataflow job has been stuck and is running from last 3 hrs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Please find below DataFlow job details:
JobID : 2017-10-17_22_03_20-14123260585966292858
Job name : limit-test-file12-1508302687176
Batch : batch
Start time : Oct 18, 2017, 10:33:21 AM
Status : Cancelling...
Region: us-central1

Job Log Details:  2017-10-18 (11:34:56) Workflow failed. Causes: (b2725d597b8162b3): The Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to t...
(b2725d597b81635e): Workflow failed. Causes: (b2725d597b8162b3): The Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to the Dataflow team at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow.

Please kill this job and let us know the reason due to which this job has been stuck.

Thanks,
Prasad Kedari

Answer (score 0):

This job succeeded but got stuck during termination due to an issue on the Dataflow service side. The issue has since been resolved. The job's VMs were already down while it was stuck, so you did not get charged for the stuckness. We apologize for the inconvenience.